# Solving a PDE using Feynman Kac formula

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

[image]

i think that the solution will be the sum of the expected value of the terminal condition with the expected value of the integral of the free term. The x process is GBM. My problem is that even i can solve the exercise till the end something is wrong because neither of two conditions is fulfilled (1.the terminal condition 2. substituting the partial derivatives in the PDE)

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: @Shaun thanks i will check it out